# Add Filter not working with get_posts

Tags: filters, pagination, get-posts

While tweaking the "Bryans Childpage Thumbnail Generator" plugin, I am applying filter (with pagination) to the get_posts for WP Pages (`post_type=page`), but its not filtering at all. Here is the code:

```
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'orderby'    => 'title',
    'id'         => '',
    'number'     => -1,
    'height'    => '100',
    'width'     => '',
    'size'       => 'thumbnail',
    'style'     => '',
    'include'    => '',
    'pagetitle'  => false,
    'selector'   => 'h2',
    'selector_height' => '30px',
    'selector_width' => '100%',
    'selector_padding' => '',
    'showimages' => true,
    'text_align' => 'left',
    'text_margin' => '',
    'exclude'    => '',
    'posts_per_page'  => '5',
    'page_number'   => '1',
    'filter_year' => '0'
), $attr));

if( $id == '')
{
    $id = $post->ID;
}

$id = intval($id);

if($width != null)
{
    $width='width:' . $width . 'px';
}

if ($order == 'RAND')
{
    $orderby = 'none';
}

if($text_margin == '')
{
    $textmargin = ($height/2)-10;
    $textmargin .= "px 0 0 0";

} else 
{
    $textmargin = $text_margin;
}

$offsettext = ($height*3);

$offset = ($page_number - 1) * $posts_per_page;

$offset = $offset < 1 ? 0 : $offset;

function filter_where( $where = '' ) {

    if($filter_year > 0)
        $where .= " AND post_date >= '" . $filter_year . "-01-01' AND post_date < '" . ($filter_year + 1) . "-01-01'";

        // e.g. AND post_date >= '2011-01-01' AND post_date < '2012-01-01'

        return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

$countposts = count(get_posts(array(
    'suppress_filters' => false,
    'post_parent' => $id,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'numberposts' => $number,
    'exclude' => $exclude,
    'orderby' => $orderby
)));


$childpages = & get_posts(array(
    'suppress_filters' => false,
    'post_parent' => $id,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'numberposts' => $number,
    'exclude' => $exclude,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'order' => $order,
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'offset' => $offset
));

remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

$totalpages = $countposts / $posts_per_page;

$totalpages = intval($totalpages) + ($totalpages > intval($totalpages) ? 1 : 0);
```

And here is the shortcode calling this plugin:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[gallery_childpages number='-1' height='220' width='295' size='medium' style='armthumbs' include='' pagetitle='1' selector='H2' showimages='0' showimages='true' exclude='1,33,22' posts_per_page = '9' page_number='" . get_query_var('page') . "' filter_year='" . $_GET['fyear'] . "']"); ?>
```

The pagination is working but filter isn't..

Comment: Remove the `extract()` and assign the result to a var. Then replace all the instances with those var contents. This will show you where it fails. `extract()` hides errors from users and the IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According with Wordpress documentation, the [post_where filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where) will not affect to the query generated by the `get_posts()` function. See also the [default usage of get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts#Default_Usage) where you can see the argument `suppress_filters` set to true by deafult. In order to run post_where filter in the query generated by `get_posts()` function you have to set suppress_filters argument to false:

```
get_posts( array( 'suppress_filters' => FALSE ) );
```

So, you code could be something like:

```
$countposts = count(get_posts(array(
                   'suppress_filters' => false,
                   'post_parent       => $id,
                   'post_type'        => 'page',
                   'post_status'      => 'publish',
                   'numberposts'      => $number,
                   'exclude'          => $exclude,
                   'orderby'          => $orderby
             )));
```

Also, you have a lot of variables not initializaed like, $id, $number, $exclude, $orderby or $filter_year.

Comment: I have updated the question with initialization code and added 'suppress_filters'. Unfortunately, its still not working.

Comment: I your `function filter_where()` you are trying to read the value of `$filter_year`, but this var is out of the scope of the function, i.e., the var `$filter_year` is not defined inside your function. As the var is defined in the global scope, you can try to define `global $filter_year` inside the function.

Comment: +1 thanks. `global` didn't worked but `$GLOBALS['p_year'] = $filter_year;` did the trick!

Comment: I forget this fact _every time_. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this condition is never fullfilled:

```
if($filter_year > 0)
```

since you haven't defined the variable `$filter_year`.

Comment: I didn't showed the initialization code. Check the updated question.